# I'm looking for options for carrying 2 children on the back

Tags: cargo, child-seat

I'm looking at the Yuba Mundo with 2 Bobike Junior seats to carry my 4 and 6 year old children.

First, does anybody know if those seats will mount on a Mundo?

Second, I'm open to all other recommendations, but would like to keep the cost under $2k, so I think that rules out the WorkCycles Fr8 and any bakfiets.  (I've got a Mundo dealer here in Chicago but would consider having a bike shipped).

thanks!

Answer (score 6):

[image: moederfiets - 2 kids on the back!]

Maybe you'd be interested in a moederfiets (dutch for "mother's bike).

This page appears to be selling them:
http://www.tmannetje.nl/index.htm?errors/404.htm~mainFrame

Answer (score 6):

The 6 year old is capable of pedaling, and would likely enjoying so. We have had success combining a single kid seat (the Yepp Maxi) with a Burley Piccolo on the back of a Yuba Mundo. This required some a bit of custom welding for Piccolo attachment, but it has been well worth it. This configuration gets used quite a lot by my wife and two kids. Here's what it looks like:

[image: Yuba Train Rolls Along]

''The children pictured there are ages 2 and 5.''

I also have [lots more photos of our "Yuba Train"](http://www.flickr.com/photos/markstos/tags/yubatrain). One some of the close-up shots, you'll find more details about the DIY changes made to put this combination of things together.

At age 4, the younger child can likely be carried with just some "stoker bars". My daughter was already riding like that at age 4.

Answer (score 3):

The Mundo is a great Cargo bike. The Bobike Junior seat *base* will fit on the rack without issues, but you may need to be creative in attaching the footrest portion, as you will not have the Bobike designed rack to work from.

At the price you are looking, I'd say this is a great option. Shipping a bike is likely to push it well above that price, so I'd stay local.

Answer (score 1):

I built my own front load cargo bike last February and love it. I built it at a hacker space here in Madison, WI. I had very limited experience welding. If you don't have access to such a space it still is pretty inexpensive to hire a professional welder to help build you one. I spent around $500 and have a totally custom bike.

http://tomscargobikes.com/tomscargobikes.com/BUILD_YOUR_OWN/Pages/BUILD_IT.html